# Sort text file in table alphabetically

Tags: php, sorting, html-table, alphabetical-sort

I'm having trouble sorting a text file and categorizing each line by the first letter.. here's where I'm at..

**list.txt**

```
Apple
Orange
Apricot
Banana
Lemon
```

**categorize.php**

```
<?php
$fname = file("list.txt");
sort($fname);
for($i=0; $i<count($fname); $i++)
{
$states = explode(",", $fname[$i]);
?><table>
<th>A</th><th>B</th><th>L</th><th>O</th>
<tr><td><?php echo [A],$states[0];?></td>
<td><?php echo [B],$states[0];?></td>
<td><?php echo [L],$states[0];?></td>
<td><?php echo [O],$states[0];?></td></tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

**categorize.php** output

```
A B L O
Apple Apple Apple Apple
A B L O
Apricot Apricot Apricot Apricot
A B L O
Banana Banana Banana Banana
A B L O
Lemon Lemon Lemon Lemon
A B L O
Orange Orange Orange Orange
```

**desired output**

```
   A     B      L     O
 Apple Banana Lemon Orange
Apricot
```

So I understand why its currently outputting double the original text file as I'm echoing it twice but I can't figure out how I can tell it I only want lines starting with A under A and B under B etc..

Comment: wait, now im not even sure the tables right. hmm..

Comment: yes the table is totally wrong.

Comment: You should do `<th><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>L</td><td>O</td></th>`

Comment: Note, use the same number of fields in your row as in your header. Your rows only contain one field while your header contains four.

Comment: first explode then use sort....

Comment: Thanks Aquillo, I just noticed that and fixed it up.. but although I was originally trying to do something impossible now it seems even harder.

Comment: Drahmesh Patel, didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$fname = file("list.txt");
sort($fname);

$category = array();
foreach($fname as $var) {
    $category[strtoupper(substr($var, 0, 1))][] = $var;
}

printf("<table>");
printf("<th>");
foreach(array_keys($category) as $v) {
    printf("<td>%s</td>", $v);
}
printf("</th>");

array_unshift($category, null);

foreach(call_user_func_array("array_map", $category) as $v) {
    printf("<tr>");
    foreach($v as $d) {
        printf("<td>%s</td>", $d);
    }
    printf("</tr>");
}
printf("</table>");
```

HTML OUTPUT

```
<table>
    <th>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>O</td>
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Banana</td>
        <td>Lemon</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apricot</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you've got a vote down because it appears to be almost working.. It's just a bit odd in display but the html seems to be nearly right. I'll have a play around and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `it appears to be almost working` ? Well your code was hard coded eg `echo [A],$states[0];` and that is not my style ,, i made the system determine the position and index automatically

Comment: the reason its only almost working is that the `<th>` wasn't displaying correctly(not sure why, probably copy/paste error). Either way, it works perfectly! Now just to learn about `printf` and how to get my syntax right. hmm. Thankyou Baba!

Comment: I've got a new problem.. I need to get some $variables from inside that `printf("<td>%s</td>", $d);` and I've got no idea how to, no syntax seems to work eg..

`printf('<td><a href="$fname">%s</a></td>', $d);`

Comment: nevermind. I was just looking at it all wrong. Thanks again for your help Baba!

Comment: `printf` can take more argument  `printf('<td><a href="%s">%s</a></td>', $d,$fname);` see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: sorry, I'll stop posting now. you were totally right to begin with.